# Printing second string causes the first string to repeat itself in C

Tags: c

When I try to execute this code with size of string `b` as size 5, it prints out

> mangoapple

Despite not printing string `a`, the output still is

> mangoapple

But if I increase the size of the string `b` to 6, it only prints

> mango

```c
int i=0;
char a[5]="apple";
char b[5]="mango";
pf("\n%s",b);
```

[image]

Comment: Mind the *null-termination*. Strings in C have an invisible extra character `\0` in the end.

Comment: Remember that a string of e.g. five characters need space for *six* characters to be able to fit the string null-terminator.

Comment: C allows that the array definition might not be an actual (nul-terminated) string. So there is only an error raised if there are too many characters specified, otherwise there is no automatic inclusion of the nul terminator if there is no room for it.

Comment: Minor edits. Those who believe this is VLQ should solicit further edits from the OP.

Comment: How do you think `pf` determines how many characters to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got **buffer overflow**.

The size of `"mango"` is 6 char and when you declare `b[5]` there is no room for null terminator.

And when there is no null terminator, `printf` with `%s` will try to print out whatever remain in the stack, in this case happen to be `"mangoapple"`.

This is undefined behavior since you don't know really what is there in the stack.

Best practice, don't forget the room for null terminator when assigning a string.

Answer (score 0):

Either increase the array with one for the`\0` terminator as mentioned in the comments above, or just print the necessary size:

```
pf("\n%.*s", sizeof(b), b);
```